# Reading from a text file and getting a different output even though I can see it in the debugger

Tags: excel, vba

I'm reading from a text file and I can't see all the lines. I can see the value of the text line because it shows up in the 
View->Locals Window. While debugging, I hover of the variable that holds the line of text and see what the value is.

Example:
This line works: *** CALIBRATION DATA - YF079305 0490-0310-5338 ***
When I hover over txtStream, after reading the line above, it shows up correctly.

This line doesn't: 8.41 25.34   2.29    1.04    1131    1156    65.54. 
When I hover over txtStream it reads nothing. When I pull the Local Windows it shows that the data is there.

My hypothesis: There's something I don't know about reading text lines that start with a number. I'm still working on this but I'm pretty stumped.

Code attached for investigation:

```
Dim fso As Variant: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim txtStream As Variant: Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(FileAndPath, ForReading, False)

Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    LineFromFile = txtStream.ReadLine
    ' Data caputre, one line
    For a1 = 0 To searchLen
        If (InStr(1, searchTerms(a1), LineFromFile) > 1) Then
            dataLine = Split(LineFromFile, vbTab)
            ' Data organize
            For a2 = 0 To dataLen
                dataArray(a1, a2) = dataLine(k + dataOffset)
            Next a2
            ' Final data found
            If (a1 = searchLen) Then
                finalData = True
            End If
        End If

        If (finalData = True) Then
            finalData = False
            For a3 = searchLen To 0
                For a4 = 0 To dataLen
                    Cells(dataRowOffset, dataColumnOffset + a4).Value = dataArray(a3, dataColumnOffset + a4)
                Next a4
                dataColumnOffset = dataColumnOffset + dataLen
            Next a3
        End If
    Next a1
Loop
txtStream.Close
```

Comment: Where do `searchLen` and `dataLen` come from and what are their values?

Comment: `For a3 = searchLen To 0` will never do anything without a `Step -1` (or whatever it needs to be).

Comment: @Sam, searchLen = UBound(searchTerms); which is 6. And dataLen = 6.

Comment: @Comintern, Thanks for the catch. I'll fix it. However, my issue is specifically with LineFromFile. It doesn't read the text correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APOLOGIES TO THE COMMUNITY! I just found out what was going on, it was two fold.

1. Where I put my breakpoint was wrong. It was showing me the previous text line, not the most current one.
2. I didn't understand that `If (InStr(1, , searchTerms(a1)) > 1) Then`
   was not the same as `If (InStr(1, LineFromFile, searchTerms(a1)) > 0) Then`. I was finding the searchTerm in the 1 position. And 1 is not greater than 1. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The input file may contain nonprinting chars especially when created under another opsys. You might consider using `ReadAll` instead of `ReadLine`, then `Split` the file by record separator, and apply `Worksheetfunction.Clean()` to clear the nonprinting chars, like this:

```
CompleteFile = txtStream.ReadAll
LineBuf = Split (CompleteFile, vbCrLf)  ' or whatever the record separator is
For Each LineFromFile in LineBuf
    LineFromFile = worksheetfunction.Clean(LineFromFile) 
    For a1 = 0 To searchLen ....
```

In general, when you run into misterious problems working with files created under another opsys or even another version of Windows, the most obvious bug is a different encoding (ASCII vs Unicode, national characters, vbLf vs vbCrLf). You might check the input file with a hex editor to have a deeper insight. Anyhow, the easiest check at the very beginning is to see how VBA reads the records:

```
Do While Not txtStream.AtEndOfStream
    LineFromFile = txtStream.ReadLine
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & ": ***" & LineFromFile & "***"
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I will also implement this going forward...especially the part about printing the File as I read it to get a better understanding.